# How to solve these two trigonometric equations?

Tags: trigonometry

How to solve these two trigonometric equations :

> $$\sin y \sin(2x+y)=0$$
>   $$\sin x \sin(x+2y)=0.$$

I know one set of solution will be $(0,0)$. What will be the other set ?

Comment: You have written one equation and one non-equation. Please edit.

Comment: @GerryMyerson DOne !!

Comment: OK, so, if $AB=0$, what does that tell you? And if $\sin C=0$, what does that tell you?

Comment: $AB=0$ means either $A=0$ or $B=0$ or both are zero. $C=0$ simply means $C=0$ ??

Comment: Not $C=0$; $\sin C=0$.

Comment: it will mean $C=n\pi,n=0,\pm 1,\pm 2$

Comment: Right. So, can you put it all together? You have two equations, each of the form $AB=0$, and that should lead you to a bunch of equations of the form $\sin C=0$.

Comment: can i just solve $2x+y=m \pi$ and $x+2y=n \pi$ and just get the result as $p \pi /3$ where $p$ is any constant ?

Comment: I don't know. You could have $x=m\pi$, $y=n\pi$; or $x=m\pi$, $2x+y=n\pi$; or two other cases. In any event, the result isn't going to be a single set of numbers, but a set of pairs of numbers, as you're solving for $x$ and for $y$.

Answer (score 3):

A possibility is $\sin y=0$, which gives $y=k\pi$ (integer $k$); substituting in the second one gives
$$
\sin x\sin(x+2k\pi)=0
$$
so this implies $\sin x=0$. Similarly, $\sin x=0$ implies $\sin y=0$. Thus we can reduce to the case
$$\begin{cases}
\sin(2x+y)=0\\
\sin(x+2y)=0
\end{cases}
$$
From this you have
$$
\begin{cases}
2x+y=a\pi\\
x+2y=b\pi
\end{cases}
$$
(where $a$ and $b$ are any integers).

This is a linear system, that can be solved as
$$
x=\frac{2a-b}{3}\pi,\quad
y=\frac{2b-a}{3}\pi
\qquad(a,b\text{ any integers}).
$$

This formula encompasses also the case $\sin x=\sin y=0$, because given arbitrary integers $h$ and $k$ one can express
$$
\begin{cases}
h=\frac{2a-b}{3}\\[1ex]
k=\frac{2b-a}{3}
\end{cases}
$$
for suitable integers $a$ and $b$, namely $a=2h+k$ and $b=h+2k$.

Therefore the general solution can be written as
$$
\boxed{\displaystyle x=\frac{2a-b}{3}\pi,\quad y=\frac{2b-a}{3}\pi,
\qquad a,b\text{ arbitrary integers}}.
$$

---

Noticing that $2a-b\equiv 2b-a\pmod{3}$, we can express the solutions in a different form, as three families:
\begin{align}
&1. & x &= h\pi,                & y &= k\pi\\[1ex]
&2. & x &= \frac{\pi}{3}+h\pi,  & y &= \frac{\pi}{3}+k\pi\\[1ex]
&3. & x &= \frac{2\pi}{3}+h\pi, & y &= \frac{2\pi}{3}+k\pi
\end{align}
again for arbitrary integers $h$ and $k$.

Comment: why $h,k$ have to be integers? Can we put $a=0,b=1$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee $h$ and $k$ refer to the solution of the case $\sin x=\sin y=0$.

Comment: As I said put $a=0,b=1\implies h=-\frac13, k=\frac23\implies x=-\frac\pi3,y=\frac{2\pi}3$ does this pair satisfy the given equations?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Why should it? Please, read again: I said that if $h$ and $k$ are integers, then there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that $h=(2a-b)/3$ and $k=(2b-a)/3$, namely $a=2h+k$ and $b=h+2k$. *Thus the formula encompasses also the solutions for $\sin x=\sin y=0$.*

Comment: got your point. Please find my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

From the first equation

Case $1:$ If $\sin y=0,y=n\pi$  where $n$ is any integer

Assuming the second equation to be $\sin x\sin(x+2y)=0$

$\sin x\sin(x+2y)=\sin x\sin(x+2n\pi)=\sin^2x$

$\implies \sin^2x=0\implies \sin x=0\implies x=m\pi$  where $m$ is any integer

So, one set of solution is $(x,y)=(m\pi,n\pi)\ \ \  \ (1)$

Case $2:$ If $\sin(2x+y)=0,2x+y=r\pi$  where $r$ is any integer

From the second equation, $\sin x\sin(x+2y)=\sin x\sin(x+2r\pi-4x)=-\sin x\sin3x$

$\implies \sin x\sin3x=0$

If $\sin x=0, x=p\pi,$ where $p$ is any integer

$\implies y=r\pi-2x=r\pi-2p\pi=(r-2p)\pi\ \ \ \ (2)$  which is clearly a subset of $(1)$

If $\sin3x=0,3x=q\pi$  where $q$ is any integer

$\implies  x=\frac{q\pi}3$
and subsequently $y=r\pi-2x=r\pi-2\frac{q\pi}3=\frac{(3r-2q)\pi}3$

So, another set of solution is $(x,y)=\left(\frac{q\pi}3,\frac{(3r-2q)\pi}3\right)\ \ \  \ (3)$

If we compare $(1),(3)$

$m\pi=\frac{q\pi}3\implies q=3m$  and $n\pi=\frac{(3r-2q)\pi}3=\frac{(3r-2\cdot3m)\pi}3=(r-2m)\pi\implies r=n+2m$

Do you see the relationship between $(1),(3)?$ Essentially, the solution can be expressed as one set, right? How?

Comment: can i just solve $2x+y=m \pi$ and $x+2y=n \pi$ and just get the result as $p \pi /3$ where $p$ is any constant ?

Comment: @user85860, yes. But in that case, we need to consider $2\cdot2=4$ combinations, right? This is one of them. Others like $\sin y=0,\sin(x+2y)=0$